# Intuition behind Showing if $f + f'' = 0$ and if $f(0)=a$ and $f'(0)=b$, then $f(x) = b \sin x + a \cos x$

Tags: calculus

I'm reading chapter 15 of Spivak's Calculus book, 'Trigonometric functions', and at some point, after defining sin and cos, he proves the 'addition formula' $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$

He first starts with a lemma:
Suppose f has a second derivative everywhere and:
$f'' + f = 0$,
$f'(0) = 0$,
$f(0)= 0$,
then 
$$f = 0$$
The proof he gives is elementary and it's at the end of the post.
Then he proves this theorem:
Suppose f has a second derivative everywhere and:
$f'' + f = 0$
$f'(0) = b$
$f(0)= a$
then $$f = a\cos(x) + b\sin(x)$$
Now at this point I was totally impressed, nowhere in the hypoteses did sin or cos appear and they magically appear at the end.
The proof:
Let $$g(x) = f(x) - b\sin(x) - a\cos(x)$$
then $g'(x) = f'(x) -b\cos(x) + a\sin(x)$ and $g''(x) = f''(x) +b\sin(x) + a\cos(x)$
Then $g'' + g = 0$, $g(0) = 0$,$g'(0) = 0$
And then $$g = 0,$$ the conclusion follows. Then proving the addition formula is actually really easy.
I am just shocked, I understand every part of the proof, but, why???,

Why, if a function f satistfies those conditions, then it's related to sin and cos. It's impressive because the only information he used was the derivatives of sin and cos, nothing else.

Is there a nice intuition behind this??

Also, how do you even think on such a proof?, it's seems so elementary but so complicated at the same time, those kind of proofs are really common in his book and really cool, but i have a hard time imagining myself coming up with this kind of proofs.
Lemma:
[image]

Comment: This is the kind of proof you could only come up with if you already know the solution.  You know $\sin$ and $\cos$ satisfy $y'' = -y$; then you need to know that (linear combinations of) these are the only solutions.  The lemma works as a kind of uniqueness statement.

Comment: It's kind of like a continuous analog of a proof by induction of identities such as $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, if you've seen those.  The proof verifies the identity, but with not much clue as to how you would have thought of that solution in the first place.

Comment: The logical order of a proof is not always the same as the order in which it was conceived.

Comment: Don't worry. Most proofs are not self evident. It requires some experience. And that's makes whole thing interesting and non-trivial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on the comments I made above, it's easier to see what's going on here if you realize the lemma above (call it Lemma 1 now) is equivalent to a uniqueness statement. So if you find *any* solution, it will be *the* solution. With that in mind, here's another version of the same proof that might be easier to digest.

**Lemma 2.**  *Suppose $f, g$ satisfy $$f(0) = g(0) = a,$$ $$f'(0) = g'(0) = b,$$ and $$f'' + f = g'' + g = 0.$$  Then $f = g$.*

**Proof:** Let $h = f-g$.  Then $h(0) = f(0) - g(0) = a - a = 0$, and similarly $h'(0) = f'(0) - g'(0) = b-b = 0$; and $$h'' + h = (f - g)'' +  (f-g) = (f'' + f) - (g'' + g) = 0 - 0 = 0.$$  So $h$ satisfies the conditions of Lemma 1 above, so $h = 0$, and $f = g$.

**Theorem.** Suppose $f$ satisfies 
$f'(0) = b$, $f(0)= a$, and $f'' + f = 0$.
Then $$f(x) = a\cos(x) + b\sin(x).$$

**Proof.**  Let $g(x) = a\cos(x) + b\sin(x)$.  Then $g$ satisfies $g(0) = a$, $g'(0) = b$, and $g'' + g = 0$ (check this.)  By Lemma 2, $f = g$.

Answer (score 1):

If you play a little with derivatives of functions, you can observe

$$(x^n)''=n(n-1)x^{n-2},$$

$$(\log x)''=-\frac1{x^2},$$

$$(e^x)''=e^x,$$

$$(\cos x)''=-\cos x,$$

$$(\sin x)''=-\sin x,$$

$$\cdots$$

Hence you notice that the last two functions fulfill $f''+f=0$. This is a well-known mathematical fact and a basic property of the trigonometric functions.

---

Based on the interesting observation that $$(e^x)'=e^x$$ one can in fact solve any homogeneous linear differential equation with contant coefficients. Because we can generalize

$$(e^{ax})'=ae^{ax},$$

$$(e^{ax})''=a^2e^{ax},$$

$$(e^{ax})^{(n)}=a^ne^{ax},$$

and with an equation like

$$f''+3f'+2f=0,$$ by plugging $e^{at}$ we get

$$f''+3f'+2f=a^2e^{at}+3ae^{at}+2e^{at}=(a^2+3a+2)e^{at}=0$$ which is true with $a=-1$ or $a=-2$, the roots of the polynomial.

---

In the case of $$f''+f=0,$$ the polynomial is $a^2+1=0$ and the roots $\pm i$, giving the solutions

$$e^{\pm ix}=\cos x\pm i\sin x.$$

---

Final note: the general solution of a linear differential equation of order $n$ is always a linear combination of $n$ linearly independent functions.

Hence

$$f''+f=0\iff f(x)=ce^{ix}+de^{-ix}=a\cos x+b\sin x$$ for suitable constants that you can determine for example knowing two initial conditions $f(0)=a\cos 0+b\sin 0, f'(0)=-a\sin0+b\cos0$.

Comment: Thanks! Really nice explanation!